# Python SQL connection error (2006, 'SSL connection error: SSL_CTX_set_tmp_dh failed')

Tags: python, mysql, ssl

I used to connect to my AWS-RDS instance this way

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host=os.getenv('RDS_ENDPOINT'),
                     user=os.getenv('RDS_USER'),
                     passwd=os.getenv('RDS_PWD'),
                     db=os.getenv('RDS_DB'))
```

or with the help of sqlalchemy, but today it seem to refuse to work with the error `(2006, 'SSL connection error: SSL_CTX_set_tmp_dh failed')`

I tried to update all the python packages (`mysqlclient`, `sqlalchemy`), reinstall `mysqlclient-dev`, manually reinstall `OpenSSL v1.1.1a` but still the same error.

**[EDIT]**

I manage to connect to the same database using the MySQL CLI

```
mysql --user=$RDS_USER --host=$RDS_ENDPOINT --password=$RDS_PWD $RDS_DB
```

**[SOLUTION]**

It seems that this is a driver issue. I tried with `mysqlclient` for python 3 and got this error. Next I tried with `mysql.connector` as recommanded but I got encoding issues (as stated in the sqlalchemy doc). Finally, I ended with the `pymysql` driver which seems to work with sqlalchemy.

Comment: A driver issue? Are you sure you don't mean library? But indeed, switching to `pymysql` did the job for me too.

Comment: I faced the same issue when installed mysqlclient in anaconda environment. I uninstalled it "conda uninstall mysqlclient" and installed again with pip(pip install mysqlclient). It worked fine then.

Comment: This isn’t working for me and I can’t switch to pymysql because of issues with the in file query... does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Worked for me too!! Kudos!!

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade mysqlclient package fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks, It solved my problem too, you saved my time.

Comment: not working for me. I tried downgrading the openssl to 1.0.2r which is also not getting downgraded as it is conflicting with a package named ```protobuf```. I've also asked regarding this problem but didn't got any answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58958531/why-mysql-exceptions-operationalerror