# django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2026, 'SSL connection error: SSL_CTX_set_tmp_dh failed') while connecting to localhost MYSQL

Tags: mysql, django, ssl, openssl

I am trying to connect to Mysql server on localhost from my django application on Ubuntu 19.04.
**The database connection section in settings.py looks like this:**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'app_datastore',
        'HOST' : '127.0.0.1',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxx',
        'OPTIONS': {
                'ssl': {
                    'ca': '/var/lib/mysql/ca.pem',
                    'cert': '/var/lib/mysql/client-cert.pem',
                    'key': '/var/lib/mysql/client-key.pem'

                    }
            }
    }
}
```

It gives the error :

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2026, 'SSL connection error:
>   SSL_CTX_set_tmp_dh failed')

I can however connect to my mysql from both terminal and Dbeaver. mysql server is up.

**Stackoverflow threads which I have already tried and doesnt work :**

[django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2026, 'SSL connection error: SSL_CTX_set_tmp_dh failed')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53385113/django-db-utils-operationalerror-2026-ssl-connection-error-ssl-ctx-set-tmp)

[SSL Connection Error while using MySQL Connector with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54485148/ssl-connection-error-while-using-mysql-connector-with-python/54493292)

[Python SQL connection error (2006, 'SSL connection error: SSL_CTX_set_tmp_dh failed')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53819554/python-sql-connection-error-2006-ssl-connection-error-ssl-ctx-set-tmp-dh-fai)

Here are my pip list results :

Package      Version

---

cffi         1.14.0 
cryptography 2.8
Django       2.2.2
mysqlclient  1.4.6
Pillow       7.0.0
pip          20.0.2 
pycparser    2.19
pyOpenSSL    19.0.0 
pytz         2019.3 
setuptools   45.2.0 
six          1.14.0 
sqlparse     0.3.0
wheel        0.34.2

Answer (score 1):

Adam Johnson's blog linked [here](https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/02/04/how-to-use-pymysql-with-django/) provided the resolution for me (I'm running Django 3.0 w/Python 3.7.4)

In my settings.py file I added the following lines per his suggestion:

```
# near the top
import pymysql

# then after the DATABASES entry further down...
DATABASES = { 
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'somedatabase',
         ...
}

# add these two lines... 
pymysql.version_info = (1, 4, 2, "final", 0)
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```